# Reading Values from String

Tags: java, android, string

I have a String with some "names" and "values" stored in it.
the style that data is stored in that is like:

```
{"userId":6625,"OtherName":"blabla","isfirst":"true"}
```

I want to know how can I get the value of "othername" in this string,
or how can I get value of "Some Name"?

I have a code written on my own :

```
        String str1;
try {
            str1 = getStringFromFile(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/myinfo.txt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            str1 = "";
        }
        String str2;
        try{
        int startindeofuserid=str1.indexOf("userId");
        int lastindexofuserid = str1.indexOf(",", startindeofuserid);
        startindeofuserid = str1.indexOf(":", startindeofuserid);
        str2 = str1.substring(startindeofuserid, lastindexofuserid);
        str2 = str2.replaceAll(":", "");
        str2 = str2.replaceAll("\"", "");
        str2 = str2.replaceAll(" ", "");
        str2 = str2.replaceAll("'", "");
//For safety , cause my userid is just a long value.
        }catch(Exception e){
            str2 ="*"; 
        }
```

It works fine, but in some devices I get unusual answers.
I just want to know, is the following string, has some kind of data-storing-method?
Is there a library to read that string into list or array?

Comment: use json parser to read the data from json string

Comment: so it's a json string ?

Comment: There are lots of JSON parsers around that will deal with this.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  But if  you also have to deal with strings that aren't JSON, then you may have to continue with rolling your own.  In my experience, JSON parsers aren't very forgiving towards incorrectly formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is in **json format**.

You can get the values from the string by creating a `JSONObject` with the string and after that you can get the values using the `get` method in JSONObject. For that first

### pass the string to `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
```

### get the values from the `JSONObject`:

```
userID = jsonObject.get("userId"); // will return 6625
otherName = jsonObject.get("OtherName"); // will return blabla
isFirst = jsonObject.get("isfirst"); // will return true
```

Check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) for getting an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your storing format seems like json so you can use any json parser. For example: gson, jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Split your string by ',', when split by ':'. 
You will get arrays like this:

```
["Some Name", "6625"]
["OtherName", "blabla"]
["isfirst", "true"]
```

After that parse values by types.

Answer (score 0):

This would help you... Get your text into string my_json. Then use the below code

```
            if (my_json != null) {
                try {
                     jsonObj = new JSONObject(my_json);

                    if (jsonObj != null) {

                    int userId = jsonObj.getInt("userId");
                    String OtherName = jsonObj.getString("OtherName");
                           Log.e("OtherName",OtherName);



                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            } else {

                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }
```

Comment: dude it's just an already saved txt file , i didn't understand why you used httpget and httppost!

Comment: ok i'll give it a go

Comment: Works fine , but i chose @johny 's answer for further use for people(for it's simpleness) . thank you for your help anyway .

Comment: @Mehrdad1373 You must use try catch function while converting a string in to json object

Comment: And You can see the same in the link given in his answer... For a better and error free results, You must use if not null and try catch function otherwise apps sometimes crash

Comment: the code you have written needs some edit , that was what i meant

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson .Add the gson jar to the project build path.

```
        String  test ="{\"Some Name\":6625,\"OtherName\":\"blabla\",\"isfirst\":\"true\"}";

        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.getType();
        System.out.println(new Gson().fromJson(test, type));        

        HashMap map =new Gson().fromJson(test, type);
        System.out.println(map.get("Some Name"));
        System.out.println(map.get("OtherName"));
        System.out.println(map.get("isfirst"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, as others encourage, definitely use a parser, I use Jackson myself.

Looking at your "data", there is one curious point:

```
"isfirst":"true"
```

If your intent is for this to be converted to a boolean by the parser, then you would not have quotes on the value.  That is, the above is a String, below a boolean:

```
"isfirst" : true
```

The following might be helpful regarding the syntax of json:
http://www.json.org/